# Connecting to SharePoint online using CSOM in a Windows Store App

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, csom, sharepoint-online

I want toe make my windows 8.1 store app, which communicates with SharePoint 2013, compatible with SharePoint online. This is my code so far:

```
var context = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

try
{
    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"@");
    if (rgx.IsMatch(CredentialHelper.GetSharePointCredentialsFromVault().UserName))
    {
        context.Credentials =
                new SharePointOnlineCredentials(
                CredentialHelper.GetSharePointCredentialsFromVault().UserName,
                CredentialHelper.GetSharePointCredentialsFromVault().Password);
    }
    else
    {
        context.Credentials = CredentialHelper.GetSharePointCredentialsFromVault();
    }

    var site = context.Web;

    context.Load(site);
    await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();
    isLoggedIn = true;
    }
```

So, when there is an '@' character in the username I asume for now it's targeting a SharePoint online environment and uses SharePointOnlineCredentials. otherwise it uses SharePoint on premise credentials.

If I type in my SharePoint online creds, it keeps showing an exception which says "The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system.". I'm sure I did type in the right creds...

Can any one help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the direct answer, but faced the same error message when trying to login with the PowerShell. It turned out that I had not yet installed the SharePoint cmdlets. After loading them as indicated [here](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2013/01/using-powershell-to-manage-sharepoint-2013-online/) it worked for me. Maybe this helps you.